What is a Rep in a time_point duration?
I'm moving from C# to C/C++, and finding the documentation and online resources (including cppreference.com and cplusplus.com) to be much more difficult to find, navigate and understand.
I've just encountered time_point, and so I learned that it stores a value of type Duration. To learn about how a Duration operates, I learned that one stores two properties:

period, which is a Period, which is a std::ratio, which is two integers (intmax_t).
count, which is a Rep. No further information is provided about Rep, other than that it is an arithmetic type or representation.

What is a Rep?
How does it store or retrieve information?
What do I need to know about it if I am casting and comparing time_point variables?

where are you reading? I recommend this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration. You can see that Rep is a template parameter. If you dont know what that is you need to read here first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

What documentation are you looking at? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point explains that "Rep [is] an arithmetic type representing the number of ticks of the duration". It's not very clear about where it gets it from, but since it's a template parameter of chrono::duration, which is a template parameter of chrono::time_point, that's probably where.

.. and I do not recommend to learn both at the same time. Some teachers are convinced that you first must learn C to understand C++ and then they never reach the part where they teach you actual C++. I hope we will get past this at some point.

For your quesiton I recommend to try to ask a more specific question. What is the concrete issue you are facing at the moment? Because, frankly, picking some part of C++ and ask "What is this good for?" is not very useful, its too openended. What do you need the timepoint for? What do you need the rep for? Most likely you do not have to bother about it.

I have a little experience in C# and much more in C++. C++ is a signifcantly more difficult language.

For the people providing links to cppreference.com, that is in fact what I was reading, as well as cplusplus.com. I come from learning with the Unity Scripting Reference, MSDN (now Microsoft Learn) C# reference, Godot and Python sites which use (by comparison) very clear organization and language.

cppreference is the best reference out there. It's extremely useful. If you are finding it  hard then that is because C++ is a more complex language than those other ones you mention. But you might find cplusplus.com a little easier.

frankly, much of what you write reads like a complaint about online resources (not yet a rant ;), but asking where to find documentation is unfortunately offtopic here. You cannot learn C++ by reading online references only. You need to get a beginners book and read it from page 1

if you were reading on cppref, did you not see the section that explains what Rep is?

I am very surprised that a site such as stack overflow can provide answers such as "get a book". Please do not be offended that I was unable to understand the standard reference documents. I am not just starting out in programming. If the sites contain a clear technical answer to my question about what a Rep is, please just provide the link.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai "cannot learn C++ by reading online references only" You can, I did that. ¯\(ツ)/¯

@WileyRush Rep is a name of template parameter. It exists only in context of std::chrono::duration. There is no separate link that we can give you, because it's std::chrono::duration that defines what Rep means to it.

"what a Rep is" It's a duration's template parameter. It can be set to anything. What it's set to will be documented individually in every place that uses duration (e.g. here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Helper_types).

I think there might be some confusion here, Rep is defined as part of std::chrono::duration but it is not defined as part of std::chrono::time_pont. So this does seem like a small omission in cppreference. Maybe it is not defined in the standard, or maybe it's defined as being identical to duration::rep it's not clear to me.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I strongly disagree with the statement "You cannot learn C++ by reading online references only". A well-designed book is worth a lot, yes, but a good reference that makes clear what the standard types and functions do and are meant for is absolutely sufficient to learn it.
In case of OPs question here, the confusion arises from the reference actually being not very clear about a specific detail.

@HolyBlackCat cannot + grain_of_salt = you_can_have_a_hard_time_doing_it :D

@WileyRush I am not offended. Your quesiton makes no mention of any reference you used. You can still add a link, that would prevent some misunderstanding. You make no mention of template parameters, so I was assuming you dont know what that is. It would take you a couple of cppreference articles to understand it (or a chapter of a book) to understand what a template argument is. I am sorry for any inconvenience caused by my comments

@john Yes, it's a small omission on the wiki. rep is a typedef for typename duration::rep according to the standard.

@WileyRush I'm confused by your statement that a duration stores two properties, period and count. I can't find any justification of that in cppreference, (also property is not a C++ term, and tends to have somewhat different meanings in the languages that do define it).

It was more than one person who recommended books, and others who claimed I was complaining. I am asking questions, specifically:
"What is a Rep? How does it store or retrieve information? What do I need to know about it if I am casting and comparing time_point variables?"
People are now mentioning templates, which is helpful. Templates are new for me. A link, or a robust explanation of templates. For example: Are they open-ended and hard to describe in simple language, similar to 'class'? Are they concerned with the direct allocation and manipulation of memory? Do they contain other types?

@WileyRush Short answer, templates are classes or functions which are parameterized by other types. Relating that back to rep it is either such a type parameter or derived from the same.

@WileyRush C# has a kind of similar concept of a generic class but they're not really the same, and it will just cause more confusion if you push that too hard.

"Templates are new for me." and there we go. If you need an introduction to templates, you wont find that in a reference for Rep, you can find it here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates (and in books ;)

Thank you for the link. Believe it or not, through my lens, even that seems obfuscated and requires deeper searching (every one of the first seven links, "parameterized", etc). I am beginning to suspect that c# leaves an impression of "all roads lead to a snippet of source code or an organization of bits" whereas c++ is more like "every type or operation is likely to be rewritten for every implementation, may not necessarily involve bits, and you will get farther by just accepting the underlying abstract technical concepts rather than trying to explain them".

I am not expecting a beginner to understand templates by reading the cppreference article (not without considerable struggle). Cppreference is as close to the c++ standard as possible while still being human readable. And the c++ standard is not written for users of the language but for implementers of compilers and standard libraries.

its somewhat like your cars users manual will not teach you how to drive.

I recommend this 1h video tutorial for coming up to speed on the basics of chrono: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Hey Howard, I'm halfway into the video and have already found it enormously helpful, with the exact kind of answers I was looking for, ie "described as base types with bit depth and/or a snippet of instructions". It is also now clear why my durations didn't operate in expected ways.

I must add however, that having now seen the video, I'm strongly of the opinion that chrono's Rep deserves its own page in the reference. As well, the page for Duration could be much more verbally descriptive, but I'm beginning to gather that "that's not how we do things in c++".

Hi @WileyRush.  Glad the video is helping.  I don't have a hand in "the reference".  Not even sure which reference you're speaking of (there is more than one).  I've had a hand in the the standard, but that makes a lousy tutorial.  In any event, just keep asking questions.  If they're here, and about chrono, I'll see them and help out any way I can.  Meanwhile I believe the answers you've already gotten here are pretty good so I won't add another.

If you are coming from C#, the best explanation for what is going on in C++ is that the vast majority of classes and functions in the standard library are generic (i.e. a template), and type parameters only need to support the operations that you use, rather than everything that has been defined in the template.
Rep is a type parameter with no explicit constraints for the template as a whole. Each member will have it's own requirements on Rep. An instantiation of duration will be mostly useless if it's Rep doesn't support at least some of the arithmetic + - * / % operators, their assignment variations += -= *= /= %=, and the comparison operators < > <= >= == != <=>
Very commonly this will be an integer type, as the standard defines a number of aliases for instantiations of std::duration from nanoseconds up to years that use signed integers, but it is equally valid to use floating point types, or a bigint class, and one duration is convertible to another if their Reps are convertible.

"every" is probably an overstatement.

@HolyBlackCat I'm counting things like std::string that are secretly template instantiations

Rep in this case is a type parameter of std::chrono::duration; such durations are instantiated on two parameters: the Rep type, which is the type of the duration's internal tick counter (read: the value that tells how much time has elapsed), and the Period type, which is used to translate between time units - specifically, seconds - and ticks.
So, for example, a std::chrono::duration<int32_t, std::ratio<1>> would be a duration type that uses a signed 32bit integer to count ticks, and each tick stands for 1 second of actual time.
A std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1,1000>> would be a duration with a 64bit tick counter and with each tick representing 1/1000th of a second (or 1 millisecond).

The other answers are very good, but I wanted to write an answer in language that would have helped me the most.
Quick but not quite accurate answer: in c# terms, the type of Ret would be Type.
Duration, the type introduced by chrono, was written for extreme flexibility, allowing the coder to store its data as int, long, float, double, or any type that supports the arithmetic operations that duration uses. You assign your chosen type to Rep and it compiles your duration to store that type. You can even specify that it uses a char.
The Period in a Duration is a std::ratio (two integers) which represent whatever amount of seconds that Rep is counting, ie std::ratio<1,1000> for 1/1000 seconds (the period assigned for std::chrono::milliseconds) or std::ratio<60,1> for minutes, etc.
For a duration that counts gigaseconds using a double and has a value of 4.2, this is the complete instantiation:
auto gigaSecs = std::chrono::duration<double, std::giga>(4.2);

Time_point holds a duration representing the time since the "epoch", which can vary by platform, but is commonly the the first second (00:00:00) of 1970 UTC.
The chrono library imposes a system of types to combat ambiguity and errors in timekeeping. For example, despite the fact that a time_point is only a duration, two of them cannot be added, because addition isn't an operation that makes sense for "two points in time". They can however be subtracted, because the difference between two points in time is a duration, and as such the return value is a duration.
More info:
CppCon 2016: Howard Hinnant “A ＜chrono＞ Tutorial"
